# Using an iframe to display google mini search results

Tags: iframe, google-search-appliance

I only want to display the iframe containing the search results when the search form has been submitted, however I'm not sure how to do this as the $_GET variables are not available to my script so I can't do

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) { 
    //display iframe
}
```

How can I capture the search results returned from the google mini (to a file) to display as in include within the webpage or how can capture the submit event for this page, which I can use as the condition to display the iframe containing the search results?

Many thanks

Comment: Posted a short answer. I did a Google Appliance search for MediaWiki sites, as well as a Mini for a custom site - but I didn't use an iframe, rather I queried the GSA on the server side, then sent the results through the Google's XSLT provided with the GSA, although slightly modified.

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` in a form's `onSubmit` event, then set the `src` property of your `iframe` to what would be the URL you use for the search.

Something like:

```
<form onSubmit='return doSearch();'>
<input type='text' name='search' id='search' />
    <!-- or whatever parameters needed for the search form -->
<input type='submit' />
</form>
<iframe id='google'></iframe>
<script>
function doSerarch() {
    var aSearch = 'search=' + $('#search').val(); // or whatever
    $('#google').attr('src','http://yourmini?');
    return false;
}
</script>
```